# Confluent jar not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-kafka

I have the below dependency configuration in my `pom.xml`. I am able to download both the JARs, but Eclipse is not recognizing `kafka-json-schema-serializer`. I have tried to clean, delete, re-import, and update the project, but to no avail.

How can I solve this problem?

**`pom.xml` configuration:**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-json-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-json-schema-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am also receiving the following error when running `mvn install`:

> [WARNING] The POM for
> io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:6.0.0 is invalid,
> transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug
> logging for more details

Comment: Are you sure 6.0.0 is available yet?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I could see 6.0.0 in my company nexus repository. but I tried with 5.5.2 but still got the same issue

Comment: The message seems to be referring to `kafka-schema-registry-client`, which is not listed in your XML here

Comment: Ok I will try to include that and test

Comment: @OneCricketeerI solved the problem..issue was because some dependecy was being downloaded from everit.so i gave the url for everit in pom

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the confluent repository under `repositories` section in your pom.xml in order to allow maven recognize the confluent dependencies. Here is the snippet:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>confluent</id>
    <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: i have already added that..taht why jar fetting downloaded

Comment: i am able to download jar only for kafka-json-serializer but no jar is getting downloaded for kafka-json-schema-serializer

Comment: Did you try to run `mvn clean install`? Also if you can check `.m2` folder and remove any repository named as kafka-json-schema-serializer and run the `mvn clean install`

Comment: I have done the both the steps as described by you but to noavail. In between the repository url is pointing to my organisation nexus url.

Comment: Do I need to delete the .m2 folder and then run man clean install?

Comment: The error shows  `kafka-schema-registry-client` jar is invalid. Can you try deleting that and run `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Yes I will try and let you know.I have logged out of work for now

Comment: solved the problem..issue was because some dependecy was being downloaded from everit.so i gave the url for everit in pom

Comment: @NishuTayal it worked for me, but can you please explain, why we need to add the confluent repository explicitly while other dependencies from different vendors get downloaded without their repo addition in po.xml?